# how to select the word null alone from a matched line

Tags: regex

I have a log in below format ,

15:58:45,999 INFO  [name] [place] [id1] [id2] [my_name,my_id,address,null,street,country,pincode] verified. Allowing access

I have to identify the word with , inside a [] and print the 4th word in it. here in example "null" is the value

I have tried **[a-zA-Z]*,[a-zA-Z0-9_]***  regex. It gives me all of the below matches. Could you please help me to get only "null" value from here. Don't know where I'm missing the logic

my_name
my_id
address
null
street
country
pincode

[a-zA-Z]*,[a-zA-Z0-9_]*

Comment: `\[(?:[^\]\[,]*,){3}\K[^\]\[,]*`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zyv9lc/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
\[(?:\w+,){3}(\w+)(?:,\w+)*?]
```

..which will capture the 4th word in the first capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q9bsXW/1).

Note that `\w` matches everything that is matched by `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: How do I check if the 4th word is null only and print it using regex

Comment: @Chinchan If I understand you correctly, you can just use `(null)` instead of `(\w+)` to only match if the 4th word is "null". Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/meaFuE/1) As to printing the result, that depends on what programming language (or tool) you are using.